# WordPress calling resful service not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, rest

I am playing with my WordPress site on my dev server trying to get a custom plugin to call a restful service.  The plugin references a JavaScript file with uses jQuery and Ajax. I am trying to call a restful service to get some data when I change the state of a radio button.  The code below gets executed, and the results to the screen are "Here are the awesome results:", so it appears that the web service was called, and no data was returned.  I have some logging in the web service so that I can know for sure that the web service is actually getting called, and it appears as though the web service is never getting called from this code.  So I have plenty of questions, such as do you see what I am dong wrong?  Why would the success function be called when it clearly didn't hit the service?  And what can I do to debug this?

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: "http://myAwesomeServer:8080/myAwesomeService.svc/GetAwesomeData/Hurry", 
    type:"GET",             
    success:function(data) { 
        jQuery(".customConfigurator").text('Here are the awesome results:');
        jQuery(".customConfigurator").append(data);

        die();
    }, 
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
        //console.log(errorThrown); 
        alert(errorThrown);
    } 
});
```

Comment: I got it, problem is I'm an idiot.  I was using Fiddler to monitor the traffic, and since I did not have cache turned off I was not seeing any http traffic since I was using the same query each time.  So if you are not as dumb as I am you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

See comment above.  I just needed to turn off Cache...